# htaccess infinite loop when redirecting everything through index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have looked around at solutions and nothing I found has stopped my infinite loop problem.

I am very new to htaccess so forgive me please..

I am currently running a WAMP server for a CMS I am building and I want to redirect all page requests such as localhost/cms/pageName through the index.php file whilst keeping the URL unchanged.

```
#disable directory showing
Options -Indexes 

#error documents
ErrorDocument 404 cms/html/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 403 cms/html/notfound.html

#index
DirectoryIndex cms/html/index.php

RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/?$ cms/html/login.php
RewriteRule ^login.php?$ cms/php/login.php
RewriteRule ^reset_password?$ cms/html/reset_password.php
RewriteRule ^reset.php/?$ cms/php/reset.php
RewriteRule ^reset_action.php/?$ cms/php/reset_action.php

# Internally redirect all pages to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . cms/index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

For whatever reason upon redirecting it redirects again and I have no idea why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to completely crash its server with a wrong ".htaccess" file containing even a single syntax error. In the event of a bug, simply rename the file or delete it

I think the problem comes from the space after the dot :

```
RewriteRule . cms/index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

.

I did not understand why you need to do this so, i inform you that you can also simulate the url rewriting

in your .htaccess file you need to write this line :

```
errordocument 404 /index.php
```

and in your index.php file you can write this to simulate the url rewriting:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$url=substr($url,1,strlen($url));  // The page url that gave an error 404

echo $url;
```

next if you want, you can create the page that gave a 404 error and redirect the user to it

```
$handle = fopen($url.'/index.html', 'w');
fwrite($handle, 'hello world');
fclose($handle);

header('location:'.$url);
exit;
```